# Dafny verifies an assert when used with an assume which does not hold

Tags: dafny

I used assume and assert as in the following method:

```
method testAssumes(x:int)  returns (s:int)
 {
  var z:int:=-1;
  assume {:axiom} z>0;
  var y:int;
  y:=x+z+1;
  assert y>0;  
  return y;
}
```

Strangely enough it verifies while it should not since y:=x+z+1 and x could be negative.
When I changed the value of z to 1, the verifies complaints that the assert might not hold.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming something that is not true. As a result, you can derive *any* conclusion (by the [Principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)).

A quote from Dafny [documentation](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-assume-statement) regarding `assume`:

> The assume statement lets the user specify a logical proposition that
> Dafny may assume to be true without proof. If in fact the proposition
> is not true this may lead to invalid conclusions.

**Edit**:
Here is an example of how Dafny could (possibly, not saying that it happens this way) derive the assert condition (`y > 0`) to be true:

1. `var z:int:=-1;` tells Dafny that `z == -1`, so Dafny can later use this fact.
2. `assume {:axiom} z>0;` tells Dafny that `z > 0`, therefore Dafny can later use this fact too.
3. Dafny starts by proving that `y > 0 || z > 0` is true. This is easy, since Dafny knows `z > 0` to be true.
4. To show that `y > 0`, Dafny needs to prove that `z > 0` is false (and since `y > 0 || z > 0` is true, `y > 0` must be true). But this can be shown using the fact from 1., i.e., that `z == -1`.

Comment: The method should not have been be verified whether z:=-1 or 1 since x is int and could be negative. Assume is about the value of z which is just part of the assignment y:=x+z+1.

Comment: Once a contradiction is asserted, you really _can_ prove anything. Try replacing the assert condition with `1==0`, Dafny will still verify it.

Comment: You are missing the point. Since  y:=x+z+1, assert y>0 can't be verified unless we know enough details about z and x. We already know about z from assume {:axiom} z>0, but no details about x except being an int. Now, the verifier complains when value of z is 1 but not -1. My question is why does it behave differently when z = 1 than -1?

Comment: The difference with `z = 1` is that you do not assume any false fact (because `z > 0` is true), hence you do not create any contradiction, hence you cannot prove something that may not be true (`y > 0`).